# Applicabilty of COBS to PRIIPs

Tags: united-kingdom, law, regulation

Under FSMA 2000 and the subsequent amendments, the FCA is empowered in the UK to develop rules and guidance for authorised firms to adhere to. These are generally captured in the FCA Handbook, itself made up of a number of sourcebooks. One of these is the Conduct of Business Sourcebook (COBS) which applies to 'designated investment business', which I understand to be MiFID-related products as well as insurance, pensions and the acceptance of deposits.

Are PRIIPs or UCITS funds also within the scope of the FCA's conduct regulation?